# Linux - How to get a string specific string from a specific line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Lets say that I have the following `DeletedFiles.txt` file:

```
test1.zip  -  date-removed='6-16-2021'
test2.zip  -  date-removed='6-17-2021'
test3.zip  -  date-removed='6-17-2021'
test4.zip  -  date-removed='6-17-2021'
```

I want to for example only grab the date from `test3.zip`.

I have the number of the line that `test3.zip` is on.

How can I make it so that when I run the following code it only returns the date from the specific file I want it from, in this case from the file `test3.zip` so that the output will be `6-17-2021`

I have the following code:

```
Line=$(GetLine $File)
LineNumber=`echo $Line | cut -c1-1`
DateRemoved=$(sed -e "s/.*'\(.*\)'/\1/" DeletedFiles.txt)
echo "$DateRemoved"
```

But when I run this it returns the dates from ALL the files:

```
6-16-2021
6-17-2021
6-17-2021
6-17-2021
```

And when I try the following code:

```
Line=$(GetLine $File)
LineNumber=`echo $Line | cut -c1-1`
DateRemoved=$(sed -e "/$LineNumber/s/.*'\(.*\)'/\1/" DeletedFiles.txt)
echo "$DateRemoved"
```

It returns everything from ALL lines:

```
test1.zip  -  date-removed='6-16-2021'
test2.zip  -  date-removed='6-17-2021'
test3.zip  -  date-removed='6-17-2021'
test4.zip  -  date-removed='6-17-2021'
```

How can I fix this so that it only returns the date from the file I want?

Comment: show us the script complete

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What exactly means "*I have the number of the line that `test3.zip` is on.*"? Do you have a variable with the line number? Show the name of the variable and the value for your example case. What is `GetLine`? What is the value of `$File`? What is the value of `$Line`?

Comment: Hi,  I already got an answer that can help me solve this problem. Thanks for the time anyways!

Comment: @MrMilkshake The purpose of this site is not only to answer a question for you personally, but also provide a database of questions and answers as a reference for others that may have a similar problem. That's why it is important to improve the quality of the question.

Comment: @Bodo Yes I know, I will update the question right now since I got my problem solved!

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Comment: I am aware that I undid more than only the solution announcement. Please apply the other changes again. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a simple command you can solve it. `grep test3\.zip DeletedFiles.txt`

Comment: This does not fulfill the requirement "*so that the output will be `6-17-2021`*". The cat is unnecessary; instead of `cat file|grep pattern` do `grep pattern file`. For `grep` an unescaped dot `.` means "any character", and an unanchored pattern will be a substring match, so it would also match e.g. `newtest3.zip` or even `footest3Xzipbar.txt`. I suggest e.g. `grep  '^test3\.zip  -  ' DeletedFiles.txt`

Answer (score 1):

I'd use awk for this:

```sh
$ awk -F"[ ']" -v file="test3.zip" '$1 == file {print $(NF-1)}' DeletedFiles.txt
6-17-2021
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`

```
sed -n "/^test3\.zip /s/.*date-removed='\([^']*\).*/\1/p" file.txt
```